# Can I use play framework with akka http(not the one in play) and disable the netty server?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4, akka-http

I'm not meaning the way play disabling PlayNettyServer and enable AkkaHttpServer which is described in the documentation by using:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala, PlayAkkaHttpServer)
  .disablePlugins(PlayNettyServer)
```

I'm meaning that taking advantage of play framework's dependency injection and other tools like play-slick, and use akka-http directly in code like:

```
class AppInitiation @Inject()(implicit val system: ActorSystem, configuration: Configuration) {

  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  implicit val timeout: Timeout = 5 seconds

  val logger = Logger("Server")

  val milkywayPath = path(Segment ~ RestPath)
  val methods = get | put | post | delete
  val gatewayExceptionHandler = ExceptionHandler {
    case e: AskTimeoutException =>
      complete(HttpResponse(InternalServerError, Nil, "Ask timeout!"))
    case e: Exception =>
      logger.error("unknown error", e)
      complete(HttpResponse(InternalServerError, Nil, "Unknown error! Please contact administratro!"))
  }

  implicit def rejectionHandler = RejectionHandler.newBuilder()
    .handle { case MissingHeaderRejection("X-Caller-Service") =>
      complete(HttpResponse(BadRequest, Nil, "Missing required header X-Caller-Service!"))
    }
    .handle { case MissingQueryParamRejection("v") =>
      complete(HttpResponse(BadRequest, Nil, "Missing required parameter v!"))
    }
    .result()

  val requestHandler = system.actorOf(Props(new RequestHandler))

  val routes = handleExceptions(gatewayExceptionHandler) {
    (milkywayPath & methods & parameter('v.as[String]) & headerValueByName("X-Caller-Service") & extractRequest) {
      (contextPath: String, resource: Path, v, caller, request) =>
        complete {
          val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
          val callerInfo = CallerInfo(caller, contextPath, v, resource.toString())
          val f = (requestHandler ? RequestHandlerMsg(callerInfo, request)).mapTo[HttpResponse]
          f onComplete {
            case r => accessLogger.info(s"method=${request.method.name} " +
              s"uri=${request.uri} " +
              s"caller=$caller " +
              s"totalTime=${System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime}ms " +
              s"resultStatus=${r.map(_.status.intValue).getOrElse(500)}")
          }
          f
        }
    }
  }

  val host = configuration.getString("gateway.host").getOrElse("localhost")
  val port = configuration.getInt("gateway.port").getOrElse(9001)

  Http().bindAndHandle(routes, host, port).onComplete(_ => logger.info(s"Server started listening request on port $port"))
}
```

and in module I can set it as:

```
override def configure(): Unit = {
  bind(classOf[AppInitiation]).asEagerSingleton()
}
```

This works. But I still want to know how I can start it without PlayNettyServer running. I've tried:

```
lazy val `root` = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .disablePlugins(PlayNettyServer)
```

However there emerges the exception:

```
[info] p.a.l.c.ActorSystemProvider - Starting application default Akka system: application
play.core.server.ServerStartException: No ServerProvider configured with key 'play.server.provider'
    at play.core.server.ServerProvider$$anonfun$1.apply(ServerProvider.scala:54)
    at play.core.server.ServerProvider$$anonfun$1.apply(ServerProvider.scala:54)
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to take full advantage of Play framework with all its features and also build a higher performance server with akka http.